# Consulta en MySQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy agregando un registro en *MySQL* desde *PHP*, pero obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error.

> "Notice: Undefined index: id in ..." "Notice: Undefined index: nombre
>   in ..." "Notice: Undefined index: sexo in ..."

Este es el fragmento de código.

```
$identificacion=$_POST["id"];
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$sexo=$_POST["sexo"];
$password=123;
$telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
$correo=$_POST["correo"];
$rol=2;
$fecha=$_POST["anio"].$_POST["mes"].$_POST["dia"];

function agregado(){
  $query="INSERT INTO paciente VALUES('$identificacion','$nombre','$sexo','$password',
 '$telefono','$correo','$rol','$fecha')";
  $agregarPaciente = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
}
```

Comment: Es todo el código?  como realiza el llamado a la función ? . tal parece que el error podría ser que no le está enviando los valores de `nombre,sexo`  por el método `POST` a su archivo `PHP`

Comment: No, en otra página tengo el metodo post para llevar todos esos valores, pero yo pienso que el error está en esta página

Comment: Como te ha dicho @Dev.Joel Siempre que veas el mensaje _Undefined index_ significa que estás buscando algo que no existe en el `$_POST[""]`, en este caso no se está posteando: `id, sexo, nombre...` Si tomas esos datos de un formulario verifica que los input tengan el mismo nombre que usas al recuperarlos con POST. En cuanto a tu query, te recomiendo que uses consultas preparadas para evitar la Inyección SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano vale, muchas gracias, tengo otra inquietud a que te refieres con consultas preparadas? como se puede modificar entonces esa línea de código o como es eso?

Comment: Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas. O sea, no conviene responder a dos preguntas en una. Aquí planteabas un problema: **no estabas recibiendo los POSTS** Si el problema ha sido resuelto se debe dar por solucionada esta pregunta  y plantear otra, si es necesario, ya que si buscas aquí o en otro sitio encontrarás ejemplos sobre consultas preparadas. Para empezar, puedes leer [esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967) es un tema que atañe a la seguridad de los datos y que conviene conocer.

Answer (score 1):

**Con esto, pero usandolo con todas las demas variables, podras asegurar que exista y no este vacia, asi vamos descartando opciones hasta llegar a la solucion.**

```
if (isset($_POST["sexo"]) && isset($_POST["nombre"])  && !empty($_POST["sexo"]) && !empty($_POST["nombre"]) ){

$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$sexo=$_POST["sexo"];

}
```

ahora seria genial si lograras pasar los datos como argumentos de la funcion
algo asi, a mi me ha pasado que la funciones no reconocen las variables que no son propias de ella misma solo si son decalaradas como globales o publicas, mi solucion pasarlas a la funcion como argumentos.

```
    if (isset($_POST["sexo"]) && isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["identificacion"]) && isset($_POST["telefono"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["correo"]) && isset($_POST["rol"]) && isset($_POST["fecha"]) && !empty($_POST["sexo"]) && !empty($_POST["nombre"]) && !empty($_POST["identificacion"]) && !empty($_POST["telefono"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["correo"]) && !empty($_POST["rol"]) && !empty($_POST["fecha"]) )
{

    $identificacion=$_POST["id"];
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $sexo=$_POST["sexo"];
    $password=123;
    $telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
    $correo=$_POST["correo"];
    $rol=2;
    $fecha=$_POST["anio"].$_POST["mes"].$_POST["dia"];
    agregado($identificacion,$nombre,$sexo,password,$telefono,$correo,$rol,$fecha);
    }
    function agregado($identificacion,$nombre,$sexo,password,$telefono,$correo,$rol,$fecha ){
      $query="INSERT INTO paciente VALUES('$identificacion','$nombre','$sexo','$password',
     '$telefono','$correo','$rol','$fecha')";
      $agregarPaciente = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu formulario está formado de esta manera:

```
<form action="agregarPacienteBD.php" id="formAgregar" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="nombre"  size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="id" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="telefono" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="correo" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
</form>
```

Al intentar recoger los valores enviados al formulario con `$_POST["nombre"]`, `$_POST["id"]`, etc... no te funcionará, porque **el atributo que $_POST utiliza para indexar los datos es el atributo `name` de los `<input>`, no en el atributo `id`**. Por tanto:

```
<form action="agregarPacienteBD.php" id="formAgregar" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre"  size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="id" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="telefono" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="correo" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" />
</form>
```

Hay que decir que [la documentación del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php) no lo dice con claridad, lamentablemente. Aparece en comentario, por uno de los colaboradores:

> Make sure your input items have the NAME attribute. The id attribute
>   is not enough! The name attribute on your input controls is what
>   $_POST uses to index the data and therefore show the results.
>
> ---
>
> Asegúrese de que los elementos de entrada tienen el atributo NAME. ¡El
>   atributo id no es suficiente! El atributo de nombre en los controles
>   de entrada es lo que $_POST utiliza para indexar los datos y, por lo
>   tanto, mostrar los resultados.